# When is xproj/project.json going away?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've been reading about project.json going away since May, also telling it will be done/removed in Preview2 tooling somewhere.

Then at some later posts that project.json will not right away go away, but only xproj which will with Preview2 be converted to csproj.

However I'm using the latest tooling, the latest .NET Core and it's still there :) both project.json and xproj.

When and what are the CURRENT plans does anyone know?

Comment: I can't remember any statement which says, its going to disappear in preview2. iirc it said that its gonna be gone by the time the tooling hits RTM which is scheduled to come when VS "15 gets done (currently in Preview 5). See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/

Comment: You can find the latest build of asp.net core [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli#installers-and-binaries). I'm not sure if the csproj is already available in this last builds. You can check there if you wanna make some tests before they release a new version.

Comment: Thank you very much, with the answer below, that answers my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written on the [ASP.NET Core roadmap](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/)

> **Q4 2016 / Q1 2017**
>
> This will be the first minor update, mainly focused on replacing .xproj/project.json with .csproj/MSBuild. Project format update should be automatic. Just opening a 1.0 project will update it to the new project format. There will also be new functionality and improvements in the runtime and libraries.
>
> As context, .NET Core 1.0 included a preview version of the .NET Core Tools, referred to as “Preview 2”. The tools were “preview” primarily because we knew that we would change the tools experience post 1.0. .NET Core and the .NET Core Tools will both be “RTM quality” or “stable” with this release.